# .BAT to install apps by dragging them into CMD

Tags: android, windows, batch-file, adb

I am trying to make a `.bat` file where it goes to a location and then executes 2 commands.
First one id `ADB Devices` which works fine but second one `ADB install` requires the `.apk` file to work. Now i have something like this

```
@echo off

cd /d "C:\Users\userDesktop\adb"

adb devices

adb install

@pause
```

but it gives me

```
"adb.exe: install requires an argument"
```

Normally i write ADB install and then drag the file into the window. How do i skip writing ADB install and just dragging the file?

Comment: You want a batch script to run each time you drag-n-drop an APK file to the terminal? Am i understanding that correct?

Answer (score 1):

When you start any "bat" or "cmd" (they are virtually equal).

The first external argument is taken internally as parameter %1 However, since that may or may not contain spaces when you drop a file on it (the file.bat or file.cmd) we strip and guarantee "quotes" by using "%~1" which can be passed as an argument to another command.

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\Users\user\Desktop\adb"
adb devices
adb install "%~1"
pause
```

if you wish to ensure it is only an .apk you could modify to enforce .apk by  testing the file extension but just as simply filter to enforce .apk by using `adb install "%~dpn1.apk"` .

Note:- that ~dpn (drive path name) is considered a dirty method of testing, but is a very simple means to not install files that are not .apk (unless you drag a file that also has a similar named companion .apk)

I do not know how adb accepts its arguments, however you should be able to avoid a bat file by selecting adb.exe and making a shortcut for drag and drop usage. That you can then use different ways, such as place in your toolbar or add to your sendTo for right clicking.  So it is worth making a shortcut to "....\adb.exe" **then modify via properties the command line** to include at the end `devices & adb.exe install` (make sure to add a space before and after), if all is well that should call the "devices" commmand then windows can pass the .apk file name after the " & inst ..."